# return updated innerHTML after updating record

Tags: javascript, php, sql-server, ajax

In a php file I return some records of a table in a grid like stack of divs (var `divid` in the funcion below) each one corresponding in a record indexed by id (`tdid` in the funcion below). The database is in SQLserver.

To edit a particular record I invoke as innerHTML the contents of an `orderedit.php` file which contains a form (var `formid` in the function below).

Then with the function below I execute the update and replace the innerHTML of the div with the contents of an `orderselect.php` which returns a select of this particular record.

It executes all well except that some times the select returns the record updated but other times it returns the updated record as it was before the update. (It is updated, checked)

How can I ensure that the `orderselect.php` is returned as innerHTML  AFTER the update of the record?

```
function kataxorisi(tdid){
    var formid = 'form'+tdid;
    document.getElementById(formid).submit(); 
    // Here some intervention needed
    var divid = 'div'+tdid;
    cdiv = document.getElementById(divid);
    cdiv.innerHTML="<img src='loaderIcon.gif'>";
    if(XMLHttpRequest) var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    else var x = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    x.open("GET", "orderselect.php?gid="+tdid, true);
    x.send();
    x.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(x.readyState == 4){
            if(x.status == 200) cdiv.innerHTML = x.responseText;
            else cdiv.innerHTML = "Error loading document";
        }
    }     
}
```

Comment: Maybe there is a problem in your *.php files. Please, let us see. Any why not using jQuery's [$.get(...)](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)?

Answer (score 0):

I have inserted a small delay in the `orderselect.php` before the execution of the select query.

```
usleep(50000);
```

This is independent and does not ensure that the form submission and the record updating has occurred before the select but in a practical way it works.
Still open for better ideas.